# Setting up bigcontentview notification as default

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm using the following code to set up a `Bigcontentview`. I don't want `Contentview`. I just wanna display the `Bigcontentview` as default

```
    RemoteViews bigViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.status_bar_expanded);
  status = new Notification.Builder(this).build();
        status.bigContentView = bigViews;
        status.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        status.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        status.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, status);
```

Is it possible by any means that I can set up the big content view as my default behavior of notification.

Now it displays an empty notification and when I expand, it expands the full  notification. How can I be able to display the big content view notification as default?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own custom view using RemoteViews.

```
RemoteViews customPushView = new RemoteViews(appContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout_big);
customPushView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, "test title");
customPushView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notification_image, bitmap);
builder.setCustomContentView(customPushView);
```

In your layout file you can specify height.